# Transaction is being committed only after closing query window, why?

Tags: ssms

Something changed in the server of our client and I would like to know what it is. Previously when I committed a transaction (BEGIN TRAN ... COMMIT) it was committed immediately, without having to close the query window in SQL Server Management Studio.
Now when the transaction is executed, without closing the window, the message is "Query executed successfully" but actually the transaction is not being committed.  When I press the "x" to close the query window a message appears, something like: "There are uncommitted transactions, do you wish to commit them? (Yes/No)" If I press "yes" the transaction is committed rightly.
My question is, why this happens? Where can one configure the option of committing the transactions only if the query window is closed? I would like to know before talking to the client.  It seems they changed something.
Thanks.

Comment: Server is SQL Server? SQL Server allows nested transactions. All the layers have to be committed before the commit actually happens. Two things you might look at, 1) query `@@TRANCOUNT` prior to and after your begin transaction. 2) Check if implicit transactions are being turned on. See https://www.sqlservergeeks.com/implicit-transaction-begin-transaction-in-sql-server/ for examples of how that setting interacts with `BEGIN TRAN`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem was a COMMIT statement was missing in a nested transaction.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a mistake in the script that was being run.  A COMMIT statement was missing in a nested transaction.